# Facebook : Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration

Tags: facebook

[image: my configurationa]

What is wrong here? If a user clicks on the login button he is redirected to http://www.facebook.com/plugins/login.php?action=like&api_key=211295588901671&channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D3%23cb%3Df207fe8ecd56db2%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252F188.24.5.134%252Ff3dedfc22a9c9ac%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dflash&locale=en_US&login_text=&max_rows=1&sdk=joey&show_faces=true&width=200 which gets me to the facebook error Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

Answer (score 8):

I believe it's because the URL the request is made from is not under your Site URL.

Look at your "origin" parameter in the URL you've submitted.

You can only make calls from the location you've defined as your Site URL.

Comment: And the Canvas URL and Site URL are on different IP's and Also both are not reachable .. I think that these adresses must be reachable in order for FB to work with it ..

Comment: @dwarfy they need to be reachable by the user's browser, not by facebook

Comment: Can you please tell me what exactly would you change? Thanks a lot

Comment: I am testing the app, so it is hosted on IIS on my computer, and I added the IP of my computer as the canvas page

Answer (score 1):

I have used login url in following format

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=email,read_stream`

as per documented in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ and it works. I get back request on my web page url provided in application config as mentioned. http://YOUR_URL?code=A_CODE_GENERATED_BY_SERVER

Answer (score 0):

Facebook needs a domain to work properly, so you'll have to register a domain instead of using just your IP. After that, it should work.

Also, post the code you're using, there might be some errors in there too.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to App Settings > Advanced & enable things ending with "Client OAuth Login"; worked here :)